# What should I do about soaked particle board under my kitchen sink?

Tags: leak, sink, garbage-disposal, damage

I recently discovered I have a leaky garbage disposal (that i have yet to fix). I think it had been leaking for a while, and it has caused the particle board beneath the kitchen sink to sag. I have been catching the drip for a few days now, but it doesn't seem to be drying, and it still feels damp. It's starting to smell a bit like mildew too.

The question is two fold:

1. Do I need to replace the particle board? It's a corner sink, and I don't think I could replace it without taking the cabinet face off.
2. If I don't replace the particle board, what's the best way to dry that space and remove the smell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove cabinet door.
2. Fix leak.
3. Remove particle board and put a box fan blowing into the cabinet for at least 24 hours. Treat the floor under there with a mold killing cleaning spray. Put the fan back while you cut the new bottom. I would do it piecemeal before removing the face of the cabinet. Which you may have to because removing the face of a corner cabinet will only give you another 2 inches or so. You would have to pull the counter top and remove the top of the cab to get a full piece in there. You may need a support under the planks in the middle somewhere but it beats destroying your kitchen.

Comment: +1 Any attempt to just dry the old particle board creates a substantial risk of a mold problem.

Comment: Well that stinks, but I guess I gotta do what I gotta do. Thanks.

Comment: I did the same thing when I moved into this house ten years ago.  You can do it, and you are allowed to curse as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the leak.Dont bother drying anything.Remove all traces of particle board and any other damaged wood. Check cabinet sides for structural integrity as well as exposed toe kick panel in front. check the floor under the compromised particle board. If all is well then obtain 2 60lb.or 80lb. bags of ready mix concrete. Mix and pour new floor in place. Smooth. 
After it has cured it may be painted to suit. This will also take care of any mildew smell.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Why are you recommending concrete?